# Shared Preferences aren't overwriting with the same key?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I've got an app where I store user's name and surname in Shared Preferences after logging in. It shows me the Toast message which I set to show the name and surname of logged in user.

What is weird it probably doesn't overwrite the data in those Preferences, because the app shows all earlier logged in users and what is more weird it shows the Toast during another Activity running (not where the Toast is set) for example when I change some of the Firebase Database manually.

I am wondering about this userGuestID... the Android Studio gave me an error and said that I should make this final because of variable userGuestID is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final. Is this causing a problem?

**Keys**

```
private static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    private static final String USER_FIREBASE_URL = "userFirebaseURL";
    private static final String USER_GUEST_ID = "userGuestID";
```

**Activity where I save the user's data.**

```
public void saveUserData(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(USER_FIREBASE_URL,"here I provide the URL to Firebase Database node");
        editor.putInt(USER_GUEST_ID,guestNumber);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

**This is how I load the data**

```
public void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,0);
        String userDataFirebaseURL = sharedPreferences.getString(USER_FIREBASE_URL,"");
        final int userGuestID = sharedPreferences.getInt(USER_GUEST_ID,0);
        try{
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(userDataFirebaseURL);
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

**Here I create the Toast message.**

```
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Guest user;
                    try {
                        user = dataSnapshot.child("Guest" + userGuestID).getValue(Guest.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    }
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your problem? Like, What do you mean by "showing all previously logged in users" and not overriden? What's your expected outcome? I'm guessing you are having some problems with asynchronous patterns.

Answer (score 0):

i am also using the shared preference to store the user data in device try this if it helps your :-

AppPreference class:-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

public static String getUserName(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getString("name", "");
    }

    public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putString("name", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }

public static String getUserSurName(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getString("surname", "");
    }

    public static void setUserSurName(Context ctx, String value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putString("surname", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

now set the user name and surname from anywhere you want in your project like this :-

```
AppPreference.setUserName(YourActvity.class, "User Name");
AppPreference.setUserSurName(YourActvity.class, "User Surname");
```

and get these values like this :-

```
AppPreference.getUserName(YourActivity.class);
AppPreference.getUserSurName(YourActivity.class);
```